# K means clustering mahout

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, k-means, mahout

I am trying to cluster a sample dataset which is in csv file format. But when I give the below command,

```
user@ubuntu:/usr/local/mahout/trunk$ bin/mahout kmeans -i /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-seqdir-sparse-kmeans/tfidf-vectors/ -c /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans-clusters -o /root/Mahout/reuters21578/root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure -x 2 -k 1 -ow --clustering -cl
```

I am getting the following error, saying there is no input clusters available and to check the `-c` cluster argument. Can anybody help me please>

Here is the error which I got for the above command:

```
16/05/11 16:09:15 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.deflate]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input clusters found in /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans-clusters/part-randomSeed. Check your -c argument.
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClusters(KMeansDriver.java:213)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:147)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:110)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.main(KMeansDriver.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Please **don't post duplicates**: [Hadoop Mahout Clustering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132651/hadoop-mahout-clustering)

Answer (score 2):

Let me copy the error message for you:

> No input clusters found in /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans-clusters/part-randomSeed. Check your -c argument.

Have you considered checking or removing your -c argument?

But Mahout k-means is really low-quality. Use something else. `apt-get install elki` and try that instead, it's much faster.

Comment: I dont have any clusters in that -c folder. I dont know what to give also.

Comment: -c  <input clusters directory> I dont know what to give in this argument. The part random seed is generated automatically.

Comment: Have you tried *not* giving `-c` then? But you may find ELKI easier to use IMHO. I didn't get any good results with Mahout.

Comment: It is a deprecated algorithm in Mahout. I think that it is based on canopy clustering, which is not a correct transformation from the sequential algorithm.